# Event code C# to Python

Tags: c#, python, events

i'm french sorry for my english,

I try convert my c# code to python but i have a problem with this one.

I have found a class event for code python at this address : http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/weblog/arch_d7_2007_02_03.shtml#e616

I would try implement this one in my python code.

My C# code :

```
// using
...

public abstract class SocketBase
{
     public delegate void _onConnected();
     public event _onConnected OnConnected;

     public SocketBase()
     {
          ...
     }

     public void TestEvent()
     {
           OnConnected();
     }
}

public class SocketClient : SocketBase
{
     public SocketClient()
     {
           base.OnConnected += Connected;
           base.TestEvent();
     }

     public void Connected()
     {
          // print
     }
}
```

And my python code :

```
from EventHook import *

class SocketBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.onConnected = EventHook()

        def TestEvent(self)
            self.onConnected.fire()

class SocketClient(SocketBase):
    def __init__(self):
            SocketBase.__init__(self)
            # How to access at the base class event from the child class ?
        SocketBase.onConnected += self.Connected
        SocketBase.TestEvent(self)

    def Connected(self):
        print "Connected :) !"
```

Can you help me please ?

Quentin.

Comment: If you're only handling events in a derived class, there is no need for an event system. Here `SocketBase` could just have an empty function named `OnConnected`, call it when the "event" happens, and `SocketClient` could override `OnConnected` to "handle" it.

Answer (score 0):

Your SocketClient `__init__` and def TestEvent indentation are off, that may be causing you some grief. Then, I see you're using python 2.7 so you may want to refactor your inheritance with the [super method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). This may also be how you want to access the parent methods and attributes.

```
from EventHook import *

class SocketBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.onConnected = EventHook()

    def test_event(self)
        self.onConnected.fire()

class SocketClient(SocketBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SocketBase).__init__(self)    
        self.onConnected += self.connected  # don't know what eventhook() returns
        self.test_event()

    def connected(self):
        print "Connected :) !"

s = SocketClient()
```

Because python is dynamically typed different style conventions help distinguish between types. [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but i have no choice, i am obliged to use python 2.2 :x

So, i had tried your code but the python compiler said "TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not SocketClient" then i tried like this :

```
super(SocketClient, self).__init__()
```

It's work but my onConnected variable has not available, then i have try this :

```
from EventHook import *

class SocketBase(object):
    on_connected = EventHook()

    def __init__(self):
         pass

    def test_event(self):
         self.on_connected.fire()

class SocketClient(SocketBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SocketClient, self).__init__()
        self.on_connected += self.Connected
        self.test_event()

    def Connected(self):
        print "Connected :) !"

s = SocketClient()

Output :
Connected :) !
```

Thank for your help.